# two actors, two action, how to handle them sequence?

Tags: libgdx

I have two actors, and want to scale actorA to 1.2 in 1 sec, and then scale actorB to 1.0 in 1 sec ,too.
how to I finish it?

```
.addAction(Actions.sequence(action1, action2))
```

but this code seem to one actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with an added delay for actorB:

```
Actor a;
Actor b;
a.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(1.2f, 1.2f, 1f));
b.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(1f), Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, 1f)));
```

Comment: If it worked for you, you should always mark it as accepted. Then it won't be listed as unanswered anymore and may save others a bit of time.